# fetch data from mongoDB, setstate and pass props to child component is not working

Tags: reactjs

beneath is my code

```
class Root extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDataFromDb();
  }

  getDataFromDb = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/getData')
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((res) => {
        if(res !== this.state.data) {        
          this.setState({ data: res}, () => console.log(this.state.data));
        }
      });
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <IRPage data={this.state.data}></IRPage>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class IRPage extends Component {

  print = () => {
    console.log(this.props.data);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container m-5">
        <button onClick={this.print}></button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

callback function of setstate in getDatafromDB in Root component work successfully,
but when it pass to child component IRPage, and click print button, result is undefined.
Thank you for helping

Comment: what does this log ```console.log(this.state.data)```?

Comment: what is the value of `res` before you call `this.setState`? And btw `if(res !== this.state.data)` is unnecessary, because decoding json that comes from `fetch` will **always** give different value then `this.state.data`, so the expression will **always** be true. PS you can update your question to answer

Comment: what is the output of the response?

Answer (score 0):

You code seems to work as you intended it.

I tried to replicate what you wrote and it's working. checkout this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqd39s78/1/)

```
class Root extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDataFromDb();
  }

  getDataFromDb = () => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((res) => {
        if(res !== this.state.data) {        
          this.setState({ data: res}, () => console.log(this.state.data));
        }
      });
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <IRPage data={this.state.data}></IRPage>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// here I have added React to import Components from, because I don't know what import statement is
class IRPage extends React.Component {

  print = () => {
    console.log(this.props.data);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container m-5">
        <button onClick={this.print}></button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```